# Show image in div using onclick and javascript code

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to show an image in div when the same image is clicked in a different div. I have the following code to do that but it is not working. 
Java Script:

```
    function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById(this.id).style.display = "show";
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img id="1" 
            src="images/gmail.png" onclick="showDiv()"></a></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img id="2" 
               src="images/calender.png" onclick="showDiv()"></a></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img id="3" 
             src="images/Drive.png" onclick="showDiv()"></a></div>              
            </div>
```

Please use javascript function only without libraries.

Comment: my guts say you've got the same id applied to 2 different elements. That will never work. For ther rest, look at simonov's answer

Comment: you should pass that element being clicked in the function `showDiv`

Answer (score 1):

It should be either

`document.getElementById(this.id).style.display = "block";`

or

`document.getElementById(this.id).style.visibility = "visible";`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such `display='show'` in css. You can use `display:'block'` You can read more about `display` property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) 
Also you need to pass `this` to showDiv in order to get id inside function like this `onclick="showDiv(this)"`

```js
function showDiv(event) {
    document.getElementById(event.id).style.display = "block";
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img id="1" 
            src="images/gmail.png" onclick="showDiv(this)"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img id="2" 
               src="images/calender.png" onclick="showDiv(this)"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img id="3" 
             src="images/Drive.png" onclick="showDiv(this)"></a></div>              
 </div>
```